# Help me understand this kanji

Tags: kanji

[image]

I'm watching a movie called A Long Goodbye and one of the characters asked his grandfather to write "Elizabeth" in kanji. Obviously the grandfather, who didn't know English, had a lot of difficulty in coming up with an answer. Kanji is also not used for specific English words like names. So I'm really curious about the answer/kanji he came up with.

Answer (score 5):

This is called ateji, using kanji to represent sounds where the meanings of the kanji are irrelevant.

> 襟{エリ}挫{ザ}邉{ベ}洲{ス}